# How would I defined a 1-1 relationship using EF-5 code-first

Tags: c#, vb.net, theory, entity-framework-5

How would I define a set of POCO classes for Entity Framework 5 with the following relationships:

Primary has a 1-1 relationship with `Secondary.Data`, and also Primary has a 1-1 relationship with `Tertiary.Data`

```
        ---------(1)- Secondary.Data
Primary +
        ---------(1)- Tertiary.Data
```

So that Primary has an auto-number (IDENTITY in sql server) Primary Key (`Primary.PrimaryID`)
and each of the child classes primary keys are also the foreign key to Primary (eg.  `Secondary.Data.PrimaryID` is both primary key as well as the foreign key to `Primary.PrimaryID`)

### Edit

`Secondary` and `Tertiary` represent Schemas in SQL Server and are represented in code by namespaces.

Comment: Can Secondary and Tertiary inherit from Primary? (As classes).

Comment: They can not.  They contain completely independant (un-common) data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Primary class as follows:

```
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PrimaryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Secondary SecondaryEntity { get; set; }
    public virtual Tertiary TertiaryEntity { get; set; }
```

In each of the other two classes you would do this for the ID:

```
    [Key, ForeignKey("PrimaryEntity")]
    public int PrimaryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Primary PrimaryEntity { get; set; }
```

The ForeignKey attribute needs to point to the name of the virtual property that you have on the object, in this case PrimaryEntity.

I hope this helps.

EDIT: Per Ladislav's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547150/ef-code-first-how-to-register-same-table-name-with-different-schema), and per what we discussed in Chat, you'll need to make sure that your Secondary and Tertiary classes, though in separate namespaces and schemas, have different class names.

Comment: I know what the `virtual` keyword means.. but what is the purpose of it here?

Comment: Lazy loading of the entities, mainly. You don't actually need to have it apparently, (per here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/368164/EF-Data-Annotations-and-Code-Fluent ), but I personally like lazy loading when doing EF queries.

Comment: If you care to join me in chat I have a few follow-on questions:  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21782/how-would-i-defined-a-1-1-relationship-using-ef-5-code-first

Comment: I can assign bounty in 23 hours.  Is an SO restriction.